# How do you set a String array equal to another string (Java) (NB: I am using I/O)?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, string-comparison

I have a program that opens a .txt file in my project folder and reads the line/s in it.  I know the file reading works so it isn't an I/O problem (or swing, since I am using that also) but when I set nim (my variable) = anArray[num] (also a variable) it doesn't work.  Note: When I run the program it reaches the println("First Declaration") so its just the setting to array that doesn't work. Thanks :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class SpanishSetOne extends JFrame {

    private static Scanner s;
    public String[] anArray;
    public String nim;

    public SpanishSetOne() {
        super("Spanish Set 1");

        initFile("spanish");
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void initFile(String name) {
        try{
            s = new Scanner(new File(name + ".txt"));
            System.out.println("setScanner");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - Could not read file");
        }
        int num = 0;
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(("Made it into the loop"));
            nim = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("First declaration");
            anArray[num] = nim;
            System.out.println(anArray[num]);
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And "does not work" means what? What happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Surely this must have been throwing an exception. That exception should be reviewed, as there would be a lot of useful information in it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I was being reluctant to add a number to the String to future proof myself.  All very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to initialize your array something like this:

```
String[] array = new String[10];
```

I would also consider using an ArrayList so you don't have to worry about the size of your array

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the array.
`public String[] anArray;` Its an String array with zero memory locations allocated to store any String.

```
Use String[] anArray = new String[numberOfElements]; 
// Here anArray will be a String Array with 'numberOfElements' memory location.
```

> **Highly recommend to use**

```
List<String> anArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you need pass through a number in List :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html this should help you for the details.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize an array before you can use it.

```
anArray = new String[count];
//count being the number of elements you want to store in the array
```